# ERRO export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER = aws; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running on AWS EC2 Getting started, command:

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER = aws; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

But the error occurs:

```
But the error occurs "salt-master failed to start on 52.24.95.100 Your cluster is unlikely to work Correctly. Please run ./cluster/kube-down.sh and re-create the cluster. (sorry!)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this specific error, but there have been some problems in AWS that cropped up recently.  Please see this PR for the fixes:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/pull/10877